# Finding the minimum and maximum value of a cluster for cyclic data

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

How can the minimum and maximum values of a cluster be determined for cyclic data, here in the range from 0 to 24, taking into account that the cluster goes beyond the limit of the value range?

Looking at the blue cluster, I would like to determine the values 22 and 2 as the boundaries of the cluster. Which algorithm can solve this problem?

[image: Clustered circular data]

Comment: And how do you define the blue cluster. Clustering means using some criterion to gather up similar samples. To me, the 2 parts of blue cluster shouldn't have been clustered together.

Comment: It is cyclic data, in this example times of the day. I have written a cluster algorithm that returns this result. It is intended that data is summarized over midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to the problem.
Suppose the data is in the following format:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np

data = np.array([0, 1, 2, 12, 13, 14, 15, 21, 22, 23])
labels = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
bounds = get_cluster_bounds(data, labels)
print(bounds) # {0: array([21,  2]), 1: array([12, 15])}
```

You can find the function here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np


def get_cluster_bounds(data: np.ndarray, labels: np.ndarray) -> dict:
    """
    There are five ways in which the points of the cluster can be cyclically
    considered. The points to be determined are marked with an arrow.

    In the first case, the cluster data is distributed beyond the edge of
    the cycle:
         ↓B           ↓A
    |#####____________#####|

    In the second case, the data lies exactly at the beginning of the value
    range, but without exceeding it.
    ↓A        ↓B
    |##########____________|

    In the third case, the data lies exactly at the end of the value
    range, but without exceeding it.
                 ↓A       ↓B
    |____________##########|

    In the fourth, the data lies within the value range
    without touching a border.
            ↓A       ↓B
    |_______##########_____|

    In the fifth and simplest case, the data lies in the entire area without
    another label existing.
     ↓A                   ↓B
    |######################|

    Args:
        data:      (n, 1) numpy array containing all data points.
        labels:    (n, 1) numpy array containing all data labels.

    Returns:
        bounds:   A dictionary whose key is the index of the cluster and
                  whose value specifies the start and end point of the
                  cluster.
    """

    # Sort the data in ascending order.
    shuffle = data.argsort()
    data = data[shuffle]
    labels = labels[shuffle]

    # Get the number of unique clusters.
    labels_unique = np.unique(labels)
    num_clusters = labels_unique.size

    bounds = {}

    for c_index in range(num_clusters):
        mask = labels == c_index
        # Case 1 or 5
        if mask[0] and mask[-1]:
            # Case 5
            if np.all(mask):
                start = data[0]
                end = data[-1]
            # Case 1
            else:
                edges = np.where(np.invert(mask))[0]
                start = data[edges[-1] + 1]
                end = data[edges[0] - 1]

        # Case 2
        elif mask[0] and not mask[-1]:
            edges = np.where(np.invert(mask))[0]
            start = data[0]
            end = data[edges[0] - 1]

        # Case 3
        elif not mask[0] and mask[-1]:
            edges = np.where(np.invert(mask))[0]
            start = data[edges[-1] + 1]
            end = data[-1]

        # Case 4
        elif not mask[0] and not mask[-1]:
            edges = np.where(mask)[0]
            start = data[edges[0]]
            end = data[edges[-1]]

        else:
            raise ValueError('This should not happen.')

        bounds[c_index] = np.array([start, end])

    return bounds
```